# Where is this variable defined?

Tags: python

reading diveintopython3 came upon this and can't deconstruction into smaller bits i understand.

```
>>> a_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}                        
>>> {value:key for key, value in a_dict.items()}             
>>> {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

a_dict.items() creates a list. But value in a_dict.items() doesn't make sense to me as value isn't defined...

whats going on here?

Comment: In plain english, your `for` is saying: pull out each `key` and the `value` assigned to it and store them in the corresponding variables. Convenient, eh?

Comment: Looking at it with color syntax on it suddenly clicked.. i noticed it was just a >>> for something in:        loop with something being two variables instead of 1. Originally i had though the comma represented something todo with the outer { }. I'm not used to seeing statements inside things

Comment: You've got it! And @machine yearning's answer offers some great clarification of the details :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a_dict.keys()` is a list of *keys* in your dictionary

`a_dict.values()` is a list of *values* in your dictionary

`a_dict.items()` is a list of *(key, value)* pairs

`{value:key for key, value in a_dict.items()}` is a **dict() comprehension** which takes `a_dict` and switches its *keys* with its *values*, returning a new data structure as the result. If you look closely you can see that in the result part we have `value:key` but in the iteration part we have `key, value` -- they switch! Very tricky, very pythonic.

If there are no duplicate values in `a_dict`, this will result the inverse of the original dictionary. If there are duplicates, since all keys in the new dict must be unique, only one of the mappings of each of the duplicated values will survive.

```
>>> a_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> b_dict = {value:key for key, value in a_dict.items()}

>>> a_dict.items()
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
>>> b_dict.items()
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

>>> a_dict.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b']
>>> b_dict.values()
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> a_dict.values()
[1, 3, 2]
>>> b_dict.keys()
[1, 2, 3]

# Try one with duplicates!
>>> c_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd':2}
>>> d_dict = {value:key for key, value in c_dict.items()}

# The number 2 can only map to one value;
# the constructor seems to have encountered 'd' last
>>> c_dict.items()
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('d', 2)]
>>> d_dict.items()
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
```

Here's a simpler example of a **dict() comprehension** if you're having difficulty understanding how they work; type it in to your interactive editor and mess around with it!

```
>>> e_dict = {n: str(n) * n for n in range(1, 30)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Value is clearly defined here:

```
'a':1
```

This means the index 'a' has a value of 1, so on and so forth.

The 2nd line just created a dict using the value as the key and key as the value from the first dict.

Comment: I didn't use the term "clearly" to offend anyone or anything. I used it because it is clearly defined, with no functions, expressions, etc, as opposed to fuzzily defined which would imply it's generated via a function or expression.

Answer (score 1):

value and key are just placeholders for the actual contents of the dictionary. This basically means for every key:value pair in the dictionary, the value portion will be assigned to value and the key portion to key.

Contents of value and key:

```
iteration    value     key 
   1           1       'a'
   2           2       'b'
   3           3       'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`{value:key for key, value in a_dict.items()}`

Is called a *dictionary comprehension*, which is similiar to list comprehensions. [PEP 274](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) gives you more details on this syntax.

That expression expanded is:

```
temp_dict = dict()
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    temp_dict[value] = key
print temp_dict
```